# Upload a file in a folder whose value is selected through a list of choices

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following Script model :

```
from django.db import models
import os

    
def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    allFiles = list()
    for entry in listOfFile:
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles.append((fullPath, entry))
    return allFiles


class Script(models.Model):
    script_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    folder = models.CharField(choices=getListOfFiles('media/scripts'), max_length=200)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=f'scripts/{folder}')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.script_name
```

I want to upload the script to the value of the attribute *folder* selected by the user through a list of choices.

With the `upload_to=f'scripts/{folder}'` it tries to upload it to *media\scripts\<django.db.models.fields.CharField>* which is obviously not what I want. I saw a bunch of people using a `get_folder_display()` function but is doesn't seem to work in models, or I did it wrong.

How can I get the value of folder selected by the user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function to [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), this function receives the `instance` and `filename` and must return the desired path including the filename.

Since the function will be passed the instance you can get the `folder` attribute

```
def script_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return f'scripts/{instance.folder}/{filename}'


class Script(models.Model):
    script_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    folder = models.CharField(choices=getListOfFiles('media/scripts'), max_length=200)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=script_upload_path)
```

You could consider using a [FilePathField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield) for your folder field